# Minutely Mean Value in R

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I want to calculate 1-min and 5-min mean values from a dataset with 1-min values.

The dataset looks like this:

```
     time     BC
1  10:40:01  2217
2  10:40:02  5776
3  10:40:03  2111
4  10:40:04  1407
5  10:40:05  2056
.
.
.
n  11:30:58  6044
```

I found a [post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/15-min-mean-values-td792903.html#a792906) where someone suggested the `zoo(aggregate)` function for this.

I tried it like this:

```
time<-as.character(time)
BC<-as.numeric(BC)
BC_mean<-aggregate(BC, trunc(time, "00:01:00"), mean)
```

However, it doesn't work. I am not quite sure if I understand the aggregate function correctly and the definitions I found online are confusing me even more. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the 'Time' to `POSIXct` class, and use `cut` to create the groups to be used in the `aggregate`

```
brk = "5 min"
df2 <- transform(df1, timeGrp = cut(as.POSIXct(time, format = "%H:%M:%S"), breaks = brk))
aggregate(BC~timeGrp, df2, mean)
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly!